# How to make the points in a geom_point scatter plot depend on the count?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, geom-point

I'm using ggplot to create a scatterplot of a dataframe. The x and y axis are two columns in the frame, and the following code gives me a scatter plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Season,y=type))+
  geom_point(fill="blue")
```

But the points are all the same size. I want each point to depend on the count of how many rows matched for the combination of x and y. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 5):

You haven't provided any sample data, so I'm generating some:

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- data.frame(Season = sample(c('W', 'S'), size=20, replace=T),
                 type=sample(c('A', 'B'), size=20, replace=T))

df %>%
  group_by(Season, type) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Season, y=type, size=count)) +
     geom_point(col="blue")
```

The idea is to count all the occurences of your Season–type data, and then use that new `count` field to adjust the size in your `ggplot`.

[image]

Comment: You could use `count(Season, type)` rather than `group_by(Season, type) %>% summarise(count = n())`.